# Oracle sqlldr when table has self-referencing foreign key

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to make a simple database where one of the tables has a foreign key that references another column in that table.

I've been able to load data correctly with SQL*Loader (using csv) before adding this constraint, but once I add it, I am not able to load data with SQL*Loader (all rows get rejected).

Is there some way to resolve this? I have been searching online for a few hours, and I haven't found anything very specific. I have found examples of direct path loads, but I don't want to assume direct path loading is set up on this oracle instance (the loading I use is conventional). Is there a set of steps I can follow to successfully load this data, or is there a parameter I can set to force the load of the data?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a quick workaround for the issue. Write a Unix/Bat script to do the following functions :

1. Assume column1 is primary key field and column2 is self referencing foreign key field.
2. Load the data into a temporary table without the self referencing constraints.
3. Now insert into the table from temporary table but only distinct values of column1 should be inserted. Column2 should be populated as null in this statement.
4. Update all inserted records of the table with the self referencing column2. Since all the distinct values have already been entered it will not cause self referencing key error.